# Why FOR loop with "do (looped content)" not working?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I really don't understand why the first batch script is working and second not. I need to use the second batch script as I need to add more conditional inside the loop.

The script counts the number of lines in `.txt` file and make a separate variable for each of the lines

this version is working

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims='" %%B in ('type "output-mp3.txt"') do  set /a "nlines+=1+0" && <con: set "_line!nlines!=%%~nB"

echo line 1 !_line1!
echo line 2 !_line2!
echo total number of lines !nlines! and name of the song !_line2!

pause
```

I need the add more things on the `for` loop so I need `do (...)`  but is not working ..

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims='" %%B in ('type "output-mp3.txt"') do (
    set /a "nlines+=1+0" && <con: set "_line!nlines!=%%~nB"
    echo line 1 !_line1!
    echo line 2 !_line2!
    echo total number of lines !nlines! and name of the song !_line2!
    pause
)
```

`output-mp3.txt` contain

```
file '...\intro\Canal-1\Videos-10.mp3'
file 'F...Canal-1\Videos-10\0HDW0N3Q.mp3'
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Note that the first run of the loop only populates `_line1`, `_line2` is only populated in the second run.

Comment: I need all lines to be populated in one run and then to have variable for each line First script is working well, second not

Comment: well, a `for` loop processes the file line by line (one line per run), so it is not possible (by design), to process all lines in one go. Maybe moving up the `)`  (closing the loop a bit earlier - before the `echo` commands) is what you want (only echoing, *after* populating *all* 
 variables).

Comment: There is a way  to have in FOR loop from first Run separate variable for first 3 lines?

Comment: like I said: one line per run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 
for /f "tokens=2 delims='" %%B in ('type "output-mp3.txt"') do (
 set /a "nlines+=1+0"
 <con: set "_line!nlines!=%%~nB"
)

set _line
```

works for me - regardless of the number of lines in the file.