# Possible to assign a variable to empty line from file .txt?

Tags: batch-file

I am using this batch to check if in the second line of my `output-mp3.txt`   `outro` word exist. If exist will do something, if not exist something else.
My problem is, if the second line is not there, my script ends.

My question is: Can I assign e variable to empty line and say `No content` or something, when my `output-mp3.txt` have one single line?

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=5 delims=\" %%D in ('find "outro" "output-mp3.txt"')
```

sometimes my file is like:

```
file 'F:\...\continut\....\KMU4DP8C.mp3'
file 'F:\......\outro\....\KMU4DP8C.mp3'
```

and sometimes I don't have the second line

```
file 'F:\...\continut\....\KMU4DP8C.mp3'
```

thank you

Comment: Remember https://stackoverflow.com/a/75058325/2128947 ? Guess what `if defined _line2` would give you.

Comment: I had to change my approach because this `for /f "skip=2 ` is the fourth in my script and they are all in touch with each other.  To see the second line in what you showed me above have to make another loop, which is not ok for the other three `for` before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "_line1="
set "_line2="
for /f "skip=2 tokens=5 delims=\" %%D in ('find "outro" "output-mp3.txt"') do (
 if defined _line1 (set "_line2=%%D") else (set "_line1=%%D")
)
if defined _line2 (echo _line2 was set) else (echo _line2 missing)
if defined _line1 (echo _line1 was set) else (echo _line1 missing)
```

Comment: all the time showing me `_line2 missing` in all cases,

Comment: OK - since you are looking for `outro`, you may get 1 or 2 output lines. I misread the source as the output.

Comment: hmm, my problem is that this approach needs 2 loops to populate the `for` and I need from one run, that's why I added `skip=2` . Can be possible` IF line 2 contain `outro`   echo 1, else `echo 0` ?  and if is empty line `echo 0` I am trying now with `for /f "tokens=3" %%D in ('Find /c "outro" "%%A"')` is doing the work, but in combination with my others `FOR` is a conflict I don't understand it, I wrote my issue here last night:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064525/why-one-of-my-for-commands-is-not-looping-in-the-text-file